# How to run a python script that asks for input in php

Tags: php, python

I want a way to pass input into a python script from PHP.
I am using the following command but can't seem to figure out a way to pass a value to the script

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

Comment: you could pass it as arguments to the `script` ? Like `/usr/custom/test.py <arg1> <arg2> ...>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example you have a simple input like this :

```
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
```

To pass it you can simply do like this:

```
<?php system("python mycode.py ".$_POST["name"]); ?>
```

you can also use `exec()` and `passthru()`

```
system("python mycode.py <arg1> <arg2>");

//or

exec("python mycode.py <arg1> <arg2>");

//or

passthru("python mycode.py <arg1> <arg2>");
```

have a good time !